# PHP can't upload file into a folder?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions, image-uploading

I have given the folder read and write permissions for all users.

The code gets to here but does not upload the file into the uploads folder.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Done"; // this shows
```

I have gotten this to work on my local server, but it will not work for me online? This is my main question.

Here is the full script, if you can help with file security then let me know! Thanks!

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php



$allowedExts = array("mp4", "wmv", "avi", "mpg", "mov", "3pg", "mkv", "zip", "x-zip", "octet-stream", "x-zip-compressed", "x-rar", "rar");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-zip-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/wmv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mov")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/3pg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mkv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10000000)   
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "File: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo "<br /> This file already exists, please upload a file with a different name."; // Could I generate a random file name and use that to upload the file?
      }
    else
      {
        include_once  'securimage/securimage.php';
        $securimage = new Securimage();
        if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) 
        {
           // the code was incorrect

          echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
          echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
          exit;
        }
        else
        {
            // the code was secure
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "<br>";
          echo "Thanks for singing up!";
          echo "<br>";
          mail("iamasample@domain.com", "New item submitted", $_POST['ctf-amount'] . " and " . $_POST['cf-message'], "From: " . $_POST['cf-email']);
        }
     }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: So what does the http servers error log show? Cause that is where php errors are logged to...

Comment: PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(upload/testfile.avi): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/domain/fileuploader.php on line 59, referer: http://www.domain.com/

Comment: I know that it would be bad, but setting the permission to 777 works like a charm. or what I know is the alternative to permission 777 (chmod 777 <folder_name>) would be installing the SuPHP extension

Comment: Absolutely no reason for making the folder world wide writable. Why? The folder has to be writable for the php process, so the user account executing the http server. So either the folder belongs to that user, then only that user needs to have write access, or you assign it to a group that user is a member of and give the folder group write access. The second alternative is the usual approach.

Comment: I have tried setting the folder to 666, and 777 but I still get the same error, could it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided us with your HTML form, am submitting the following and is too long as a comment.

One possible reason why your code is not working, is that your form may be missing essential parts.

- A POST method
- A valid enctype

I.e.:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your_handler.php">
```

Also, your input. It should contain the "name" attribute.

I.e.:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

If your form already contains those, then use error reporting to see if it returns anything else.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Reference(s):**

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php